# Disabling "Allow members to share the site" in SharePoint 2016 Programmatically

Tags: permissions, requestaccessmail

I can't find any API with a method or property to disable this feature when a new site is created.  These two checkboxes under "Access Request Settings" are enabled by default.  I can apparently set the Request Access e-mail address in code but nothing else.  Help

Bismarck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.  In its simplest form

```
Using site As New SPSite(siteUrl)
    Using web As SPWeb = site.OpenWeb(webUrl)
        web.RequestAccessEmail = "TheBigKahuna@contoso.com"
                web.MembersCanShare = False
        End Using
End Using
```

Comment: MemberCanShare doesn't appear to be a property of Web in the copy of Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll that I've got. Which does appear to be dated 2014 to is pretty out of date. Anyone know where I can get the latest version?

Comment: Ahh... had to grab the latest version of the SharePoint Client SDK